# Invoke Lambda Function for 30 minutes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create a lambda function that is scraping data from Wikipedia. A number of scripts are running in the same lambda that has an execution time of more than 30minutes. The issue here is Lambda timeout after 15minutes. I got some idea to use the step function to re-run the lambda, but I have no idea how to start the lambda from where it left the other time.

I don't have the option to use any other AWS services.

**Runtime: Python**

Comment: You should probably not be running a lambda function that is spending 30 minutes scraping data from wikipedia- thats an awful lot of requests! To your actual question, what you want isn't possible. Instead, you'll have to break your function into smaller parts that can run separately and perhaps have a final function that composes the results together into a final result.

Comment: The right solution is probably to make your function take less time.  Maybe it could fan out into a larger set of smaller tasks?

Comment: I would break this into smaller Lambda functions and build a Workflow using AWS Step Functions. You can chain Lambda functions together to create a workflow.

Comment: as a genral rule for lambda if it take more than 15 minutes then don't use lambda so either break your workflow and use step functions or don't use lambda at all, the same can be achieved using constainers deployed by fargate!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can not run a Lambda for more than 900 seconds (15 minutes). That is a hard limit at this time.

As others mentioned, you could use Step Functions or use other services like EC2 or change the design of your "application".

But maybe you should stop scraping Wikipedia and instead use Wikidata (which is basically an API for all the data in the Wikipedia).

Check it out: https://www.wikidata.org